# First Android Test Project does not start

Tags: android

I'm creating my first android application but it does not start at all.

In my src > android.SampleApp I created a java file named Main.java with:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

// Will be connected with the buttons via XML
public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn1:
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtContent)).setText("Button 1 Clicked");
        break;
    case R.id.btn2:
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtContent)).setText("Button 2 Clicked");
        break;

    }
}
}
```

In my res > layout > main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello" android:id="@+id/txtContent"/>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button One" android:id="@+id/btn1"></Button>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button Two" android:id="@+id/btn2"></Button>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="android.SampleApp"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">


</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

I get this error:

1. [2010-02-02 01:46:26 - SampleApp]Android Launch!
2. [2010-02-02 01:46:26 - SampleApp]adb is running normally.
3. [2010-02-02 01:46:26 - SampleApp]No Launcher activity found!
4. [2010-02-02 01:46:26 - SampleApp]The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
5. [2010-02-02 01:46:26 - SampleApp]Performing sync

Lines 3 and 4 is highlighted red.

Could someone lead my in the right direction to just get the application to show on the emulator?

Android 2.1 SDK with Eclipse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing the following in your `<activity>` tag in your manifest file:

```
        <intent-filter . . . >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

For more info see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)

Comment: Could you edit mine above and give the complete ting because I dont know where to put that code.

Comment: It goes between `<activity android:name=".Main">` and `</activity>`, which itself goes inside your `<application>` tag.

Comment: If you search for "android.intent.action.MAIN" inside that page I linked to, you will see a good example.

Comment: @Shawn It turns out that your problem will occur based on the way you create your project. If its done following the outline in the official Android tutorials it will create it for you.

Comment: @ GatesReign.. can you please elaborate on "It turns out that your problem will occur based on the way you create your project.If its done following the outline in the official Android tutorials it will create it for you".. because I think I always follow the official Android tutorial way on how to create projects