# No Launcher activity found! For a widget? Does it have to be an activity

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget that I've developed and it runs fine on my emulator. But when I go to and run it on my device it doesn't show up in the list

Here is what my console says:

```
[2010-10-14 12:43:43 - MyWidget] No Launcher activity found!
[2010-10-14 12:43:43 - MyWidget] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!**
[2010-10-14 12:43:43 - MyWidget] Performing sync
[2010-10-14 12:43:43 - MyWidget] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'D70068f58fd3'
[2010-10-14 12:43:43 - MyWidget] Uploading MyWidget.apk onto device 'D70068f58fd3'
[2010-10-14 12:43:43 - MyWidget] Installing MyWidget.apk...
[2010-10-14 12:43:45 - MyWidget] Success!
[2010-10-14 12:43:45 - MyWidget] /MyWidget/bin/MyWidget.apk installed on device
[2010-10-14 12:43:45 - MyWidget] Done!
```

I can see that indeed the application package is on my device via the Applications manager.

I've seen the other posts on SO:
[Android sample app not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347569/android-sample-app-not-showing-up)
[launching android widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888383/launching-android-widget/3936481#3936481)
and 
[First Android Test Project does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186758/first-android-test-project-does-not-start)

But I have a widget. Is that different?  And here is my AndroidManifest.xml, which does indeed have a Launcher defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.example.widget"
android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <receiver android:name=".MyWidget"
              android:label="Anything">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Comment: Is your Epic4g device the device specified as 'D70068f58fd3' ?

Comment: Yes it is. Does that mean anything?

Comment: @b-ryce: On a whim, try rebooting the phone. We've seen devices have problems with too-aggressively caching things. Perhaps the Epic only reads the roster of possible widgets when the home screen activity first runs. If this turns out to be the case, you would see your widget as an option on a reboot. If this works, please @ me back, as I am trying to ensure problems like this do not occur with other devices in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I tried rebooting and I still don't see it in the list of widgets to add. Is there another way I can verify if the widget is on my phone?

Comment: @b-ryce: Does the widget appear under the Manage Applications listing?

Comment: @Brian Mansell, Yes I see it there.  Good question. Any idea why I can't get it to show up in the widgets list?  I see other widgets that didn't come with the phone, I see ones that I downloaded.  The next thing I'm going to try is to put it on another android device and see if that works.

Comment: I just installed the widget on a Nexus 1 and had the same result. (didn't show up in the widget list, but was in the Manage Applications listing) I'm assuming there is some setting in my project that makes it invisible to the widget list?

Answer (score 0):

In your XML Manifest you have configured a receiver and not an activity.
Try something like that

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <receiver android:name=".MyWidget"
              android:label="Anything">
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name="YourActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```